# Dataframe loc from series, python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dataframe

I have Series where the index and column name are stocked. 
I want to print only the index and column from Series and not whole dataframe.

```
Series
0       wkeans
1     wContour
2    wDarkBand
3     wContour

Dataframe
     wContour  wDarkBand  wkeans
0   92.000000        0.0    94.0
1   90.000000       88.0    84.0
2   84.000000       86.0    84.0
3   84.000000        0.0   102.0
```

I want to have :

[image]

I.e. :

```
94.0
90.0
86.0
84.0
```

dfW.loc[myseries], dfW.loc[s.index, s.values] do not work, any suggestion ?

Thanks

Comment: Your desired output has no index. Yet your question suggests you want index & values. Can you please clarify?

Comment: I add some colors, hope that it is clearer,
I want to print only values of dataframes

Comment: Sorry, still not clear how you got the yellow highlighting for 94/90/86/84 output.

Comment: It is just to explanation what I want, I did it with paint. And I want to achieve it with pandas.

Comment: So what's your **logic** to extract the yellow values? Just random. By row index & column name? This is still unclear.

Comment: Using the linked `DataFrame.lookup` method, you could use `df.lookup(df.index, s)`.

Comment: No, it is not random, they are taken from Series, did you get that ?